# I am confuse to use fiber optic cable, Rj45 or current cat6 cable?

Tags: networking, cable, rj-45, fiber

We want to do networking again, server room is on first floor connected to 25M cat6 UTP cable with ground floor DLink router modem(DSL-2750U).(I can not change this cable as it done during construction). I am not happy with two jointer use in this 25M cable. plus we have to connect our other two department which are approx 100M away. It is confusing me whether two jointers will affect the link between server n modem or I go for 100meter fiberoptic or cat6e cable? please help

Comment: By jointer you're talking about one of those ethernet adpaters/extenders that got one port on either side? It's not clear what you actually want to do or whats giving you trouble. Inter building fiberoptics might be a good option. Within a building a cat6 or 7 cable would probably be sufficient. 100m is considered the max length of normal Ethernet segment.

Comment: Any jointing of a cable will lessen its integrity and reduce its efficiency. Whilst you may be able to measure continuity, the dB level will not improve the signal to the extent that a single cable of similar length will. As @nasir Hussain says, the theoretical max length of an Ethernet twisted pair segment is 100m after which you will potentially begin to impair data quality. Typical transmission speed and distance limits for fibre optic are 100 Mbit/s for distances up to 2 km (100BASE-FX), 1 Gbit/s up to 1000 m, and 10 Gbit/s up to 550 m.

Comment: Fiber optic and cat6 are mediums, RJ45 is a connector type that generally goes to the cat5/6 medium. Fiber optic cables require a different type of connector, specifically an optical transceiver, which means you need a port than can handle those (generally higher end switches, not Dlink), so you're best sticking with cat6/RJ45 unless you have a real need to upgrade to enterprise level equipment. Cat6 can handle 100M.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done fiber optic cabling media, it has been more than 3years but still, no troubleshooting was ever required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out out by others a coupler in the fixed plant is unusual.  It is an additional point of failure and often easily overlooked.  A patch panel with a patch lead between two fixed cable is essentially the same as it adds two extra connections, however it is obvious and hard to miss

So my point is if it's an already installed installation with a cat 6 coupler or two and the total it's less than 100m total length of cable then yes it should still run at full speed.   That is if you are with in the specifications it should work.  It won't run faster at 25m vs 100m.  If the cables you have work  without errors then changing to fibre will not increase the speed unless you upgrade the hardware to faster links.

I'd suggest you check if you are getting errors on the link before deciding to run new cables also don't expect speed increases with a change in cabling

Comment: Couplers really shouldn't be used for production purposes, they are best used only for testing. They introduce additional points of failure, which is less than ideal for a permanent solution.